# Wait for variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using nodeJS. I want to wait for a property inside an object to become true, and then continue code execution.

Here's what my code looks:

```js
export async function createRun() {
    try {
        let shared = { url: "", device: "", finished: new Promise(() => {}) };

        const browser = await launch();

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

        await page.setBypassCSP(true);

        await page.exposeFunction(
            "onMessageReceivedEvent",
            async (e: { type: string; data: Message }) => {
                if (e.data === "finished") {
                    shared.finished = ;
                }
            }
        );

        const listenFor = (type: string) => {
            return page.evaluateOnNewDocument((type: any) => {
                window.addEventListener(type, (e) => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    window.onMessageReceivedEvent({ type, data: e.data });
                });
            }, type);
        };

        await listenFor("message");

       console.log('before');
       // wait for shared.finished to become true
       // continue execution
       console.log('after')
}
```

How can this be implemented? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ideally the object will broadcast a message for when its state changes (perhaps when it's finished) and you would subscribe to that.

Comment: A bit more context would help. Sounds like `finished` is set to `true` trough some asynchronous task. So you might want to utilize Promises and `await` for that.

Comment: No it's not asynchronous, it changes on an event based subscription. That's not really related, and promises can't be used

Comment: Doing requests or reading files is also event based and those can be converted to Promises as well. A subscription is just another asynchronous way to get notified about something. Whether or not you can utilized a promise there depends on the exact use case.

Comment: @t.niese it's not that, I'm using puppeteer, which has an event listener for a `postMessage` from an executed script. This function will then set the `finished` variable to true

Comment: So, it's still an async task that sets the value to true. Just not the object itself doing the async task.

Comment: @Akash I still see no reason why this could not work with Promises. It depends when and how you set up puppeteer and the event listener.

Comment: There is a lot more complexity and code involved, so I don't want to use promises. Is there an alternative? also, why is my question downvoted?

Comment: You are very vague about how all is tight together. Either you use Promises, with something like `await yourPuppeteerTask.finished()` (I don’t see why this should make any code more complex) or you need to implement some other notification system in you puppeteer related code using callbacks or subscriber observer pattern which likely increases the complexity more then using promises.

Comment: Not using promises is likely going to be *more* complex, not less...As in, you literally cannot do it. There is no option to say "wait until this property changes". You can: 1. make an async task that fires off every X time units and polls the value of the property and if correct, *then* execites some code (setTimeout/setInterval can work but I'd honestly still wrap that in a promise). 2. You can make the object observable so you subscrube to changes to it. Or at the very least make it emit some sort of message to listen to. Both of these are not *less* complex than using a promise.

Comment: I've updated the code with more details, do check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now having all details, it is possible to answer your question.

Getting the result thought an exposed function might - at first sight - prevent the usage of a Promise. But you can utilize closures for that.

So you create your callback function within a `new Promise`, and assign it to a variable outside of that. In your callback, you can `resolve` that promise when your condition `e.data === "finished"` is met.

```js
        let onMessageReceivedEventCallback;
        const messageReceived = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          onMessageReceivedEventCallback = (e: { type: string; data: Message }) => {
              if (e.data === "finished") {
                  resolve();
              }
              // TODO you might want to reject in case an error occurs here, so that your application won't halt
          }
          // TODO if there is no specific error case then you might reject here after a given timeout
          // setTimout(() => reject(new Error("Timeout")), 1000);
        })
```

And you then pass that function to your `page.exposeFunction`, and later you use `await messageReceived` to wait for that promise to be resolved.

```js
export async function createRun() {
    try {
        let shared = { url: "", device: "" };

        const browser = await launch();

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

        await page.setBypassCSP(true);

        
        let onMessageReceivedEventCallback;
        const messageReceived = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          onMessageReceivedEventCallback = (e: { type: string; data: Message }) => {
              if (e.data === "finished") {
                  resolve();
              }
              // TODO you might want to reject in case an error occurs here, so that your application won't halt
          }
          // TODO if there is no specific error case then you might reject here after a given timeout
          // setTimout(() => reject(new Error("Timeout")), 1000);
        })


        await page.exposeFunction(
            "onMessageReceivedEvent", onMessageReceivedEventCallback
        );

        const listenFor = (type: string) => {
            return page.evaluateOnNewDocument((type: any) => {
                window.addEventListener(type, (e) => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    window.onMessageReceivedEvent({ type, data: e.data });
                });
            }, type);
        };

        await listenFor("message");

       console.log('before');
       await messageReceived;
       console.log('after')
}
```

To answer your original question, it is technically possible to achieve something like that using getter, setters, or Proxy. In the following, I show how something like that could be done using a Proxy. But please note that I highly discourage the usage of that. It just obscures what is going on in the code, and I can't imagine a use-case where this really makes sense.

```js
function createWaitAbleProperties(initialObject = {}, timeout = 2000) {

  function initProperty(obj, name) {
    obj.properties[name] = {}
    
    // utelizing a defere pattern which is not recommended
    // it is not as bas as the regular one due to the timeout but it is still bad
    obj.properties[name].promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      obj.properties[name].resolve = resolve
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout for ' + name)), timeout);
    })
  }

  return new Proxy(initialObject, {
    properties: {},
    get: function(obj, prop) {
      let match;
      if (match = prop.match(/^(.*)Promise$/)) {
        if (!this.properties[match[1]]) {
          initProperty(this, match[1])
        }
        return this.properties[match[1]].promise
      } else {
        return this.properties[prop]?.value
      }
    },
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
      if (!this.properties[prop]) {
        initProperty(this, prop)
      }
      this.properties[prop].resolve()
      this.properties[prop].value = value
    }
  });
}


async function run() {
  const observer = createWaitAbleProperties()
  
  observer.value2 = 200

  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.value1 = 100
  }, 1000)

  await observer.value1Promise
  await observer.value2Promise
  console.log('finished', observer.value1, observer.value2)
}

run()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer, I think there's a syntax error where you define `onMessageReceivedEvent`. I think it should be `onMessageReceivedEventCallback`, but let me know :)

Comment: @Akash yes that was a mistake. I updated that before you wrote your comment.

Answer (score -3):

You need some design pattern, like  Publishers + Subscribers or Observer Pattern.

Comment: Well, could you give a short example of this?